# Setting the a caret in an JEditor Pane causes an exception

Tags: java, caret, jeditorpane

I have a JeditorPane which has some text in HTML format.   When I execute the following command

int len = editorPane.getText().length();

The value for len is 7473.    But then I try to do the following:

editorPane.setCaretPosition(4995);

And I get the following exception:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad position: 4995

My understanding is that I should only get this exception if the position at which I'm trying to set the caret is less than 0 or greater than the text length.    It is neither.   How can this be.

Thank you,

Elliott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int len = editorPane.getText().length();
```

Gives you the length of the text and the tags.

Try using:

```
int len = editorPane.getDocument().getLength();
```

which will only give you the length of the text in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the text does not only contains renderable characters (you have HTML tag in the text). I guess that setCaretPosition want's to get visible text position.

For example, if `text = "<b>123</b>"` and you call `editorPane.setCaretPosition(2)`, I think that the caret will be between '2' and '3';